# Failed to execute DialogFragment in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

When I try to execute the `DialogoFragment` in a `Fragment`, it tells me to create the Show method and I already tried with: this, getContext (), `getFragmenteManager ()`, `getActivity (). GetFragmenteManager ().`
In the `Activity` it does not give me problems to execute it only in the Fragment.

I am running this code from a Fragment:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 btnComentario = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnComentario);
 btnComentario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      (new MyDialogFragment()).show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "DialogFrament");
      }
    });

}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Create an object of your dialog and call method build and then show on it

Comment: Don't put code in Title of query.

Comment: If this is what it tells me, if I have tried it and it does not work for me. 
I get the same                              DialogFragment de Diálogo = new MyDialogFragment (); dialog.show (getActivity () getFragmentManager () "DialogFrament".);

Comment: Sorry for the title, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
 btnComentario = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnComentario);
 btnComentario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
            dialogFragment.show(fm,"");
      }
    });
}
```

Try this method on onViewCreated inside fragment. It's working solution.
If it works fine kindly Tick the answer so as to pass info for researchers.

Comment: Thanks but I get the same: Cannot resolve method show.

Comment: post your Log Here.

Comment: Check Your Import use 

`import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;`

Comment: Yes i have imported

Comment: Post your full code and your error Log for much clarity

Comment: I do not get error, just do not let me declare it. That is to say I get the arguments in red and winged the bulb telling me: Cannot resolve method show

Comment: Check your fragment import use - `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`
your fragment manager import use - `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Comment: Thanks was that, I had some with app and others with support.v4. I've put them all with app, now it does not give error or failure to write it but I do not execute the DialogoFragment.
It is implemented and both the DialogoFragment and the executor uses the app implementations. Do you know why it could be?

Comment: Could you brief your query more? If the issue with the question has finished you can mark the answer as correct by selecting tick so it can help other researchers.

Comment: No me da ningún fallo, pero al ejecutar el diálogo, la aplicación es closes.Everything con: android.app importación.  (new AddMyDialogFragment()).show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialogFragment");

Comment: It does not give me any flaws, but when I run the dialog, the application is closes.Everything with: import android.app.   Code: (new AddMyDialogFragment()).show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialogFragment");

Comment: Kindly post this as a new question with the error log for much clarity.